# How to validate trading strategy performance

Tags: programming, backtesting, algorithmic-trading

I'm backtesting some algorithmic trading strategy based on the buy/sell signals:
[image]

To validate the strategy performance I compare it against the buy-and-hold strategy of the same asset and calculate the following metrics:

- the strategy total return
- the strategy Calmar/Sharpe ratios
- the strategy trades win/loss ratio

First of all, I want to add another metrics based on the trades win/loss positions. For example, I assume that the following trades (`1`-win, `-1`-loss):
`1,-1,1,-1,1,-1`
are better than these trades:
`1,1,1,-1,-1,-1`
Second, I would like to replace all these ratios with 1 generic metric, if such exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not exist a single metric that encompasses all your criteria; but you could simply construct a (linear or non-linear) combination of the measures you like. For the win/loss streaks you describe, you could either look at the absolute maximum drawdown of the cumulative series (`1` in the first case, `3` in the second), or look at streaks and penalise streaks of `-1`s. For instance, in R:

```
library("NMOF")
drawdown(cumsum(c(1,-1,1,-1,1,-1)), relative = FALSE)$maximum
## [1] 1
drawdown(cumsum(c(1,1,1,-1,-1,-1)), relative = FALSE)$maximum
## [1] 3
```

For streaks, look at function `rle`.

Comment: Yes, I see. I'll add also max drawdown and drawdown duration metrics and order strategies according to each ratio ranks.